# axios response.data is empty when django returns a queryset with a single element

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, axios, django-serializer

I am using axios to get some data from my backend API made with django.
Something very very wired is happening and I have been debugging this for hours.

This is the axios function that gets the data:

```js
function useGetProducts(category: string, subcategory: string, code:string){
    const [products, setProducts] = useState<Product[]>([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(getQueryUrl(category, subcategory, code))
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                setProducts(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    },[]);
    return products;
}
```

And here is my ProductView in django

```py
class ProductView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        cat = self.request.query_params.get('category', None)
        subcat = self.request.query_params.get('subcategory', None)
        code = self.request.query_params.get('code', None)
        if cat and subcat and code:
            # Sanitize the name parameter using Django's ORM
            queryset = queryset.filter(code__exact=code)
        elif cat and subcat:
            queryset = queryset.filter(category__exact=cat, sub_category__exact=subcat)
        elif cat:
            queryset = queryset.filter(category__exact=cat)
        print(queryset)
        return queryset
```

Now the thing is when the `queryset` contains only one element the `response.data` is an empty array but when the `queryset` contains more than one element the `response.data` contains the right amount of elements.

The method `getQueryUrl` works correctly. I tried to limit the output of other querysets that supposed to contain more than 1 element to 1 and same thing, empty array on the frontend side.

ChatGPT solution did not help either. It suggested that Django REST Framework serializes single objects differently from lists of objects and said that overriding the `list` method would fix the problem...but nope it didn't.

I highly believe the problem is with the API, most likely with django-rest-framework (DRF) but I'm new to django and don't know what may be causing this. Would appreciate any help.

By the way I am using the default DRF configurations.

Comment: What happens when you call it from the command line using `httpie`: `http :8000/api/endpoint/ category==x`, does it show the data.  What does `queryset.count()` show there? What does `print(queryset.query)` show?  What debugging have you actually done here?  Why not show `getQueryUrl`?  How does ChatGPT show you to debug this?

Comment: Hi @Andrew, sorry for the late response, I was hospitalized... When I access it directly with the api link it shows me the correct object in json. `print(queryset.query)` prints `<QuerySet [<Product: Product object (15)>]>` Its still correct. I did not show `getQueryUrl` because it provides the correct url as output, I have already debugged that. ChatGPT suggests that the issue may be related to how Django REST Framework serializes the queryset when it contains a single object and it tells me to define the list method in ProductView but that does not fix the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure then, and GPT should generally be ignored.  Something has to be omitted here: if your code and the location of the print() is accurate then nothing looks wrong.  Please add the output of a CURL request for that endpoint to verify the actual data returned.  I would expect an issue in `setProduct`, since this is standard functionality and certainly isn't broken: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Comment: Also, `print(queryset.query)`  will not print `<Queryset(...`, it will print the SQL of the query so you can verify it.

Comment: I noticed that if i remove the line `setProducts(response.data)` the `console.log` above prints the right data. So you are right, it has to do with `setProduct`. I'll have a better look on that. React hooks are new to me :/. Anyway thank you a lot!